# Dynamically expanding Django forms

Tags: python, django

I would like to create a form where a user can enter an arbitrary # of items in separate textboxes. The user could add (and potentially remove) fields as needed. Something like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [eggdrop.ch](http://www.eggdrop.ch/downloads/dynamicforms/dynamicforms.png))</sub>

I found the following different solutions:

http://www.eggdrop.ch/blog/2007/02/15/django-dynamicforms/

http://dewful.com/?p=100

These methods both appear a bit involved. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Additional detail: using Google App Engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a [new feature](http://djangoadvent.com/1.2/jquery-admin/#new-features) in the admin in Django 1.2.

Maybe you can take a look at the way they implemented it there.

Comment: Thanks; will see what I can do with this.

Comment: Link is dead. Can you provide another?

Comment: i'd like to see a new link too.